# Close a dialog by clicking the modal iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dialog, modal-dialog

I am creating a modal dialog box. First I append an iframe to the `body` tag to act as my overlay.

```
<div class="modal-screen">
  <iframe src="javascript:false;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Then I append my dialog box to the `body`.

```
<div class="dialog">
  <!-- various dialog related elements
</div>
```

Now I would like to close the dialog when the user clicks the overlay. The problem is that I can't seem to bind to any events related to the overlay.

To summarize my JS, basically my dialog view has an `initialize` method where the overlay is prepared:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.modal = $('<div class="modal-screen"><iframe src="javascript:false;"></iframe></div>')

  this.modal.on('click', function(e) {
    // this event never seems to fire
    console.log("hello");
  }
}
```

Then I render into the page when I need it. When I click the overlay, I never see `hello`..

```
render: function() {
  $('body').append(this.modal);
  // append other dialog content
  this
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to be using an iframe here. Simply construct an [overlay div](http://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/), then remove it when it is clicked.

Comment: I've read in [Designing with Progressive Enhancement](http://filamentgroup.com/dwpe/) that it is best to use an iframe. However, the solution you suggest seems to work fine so I'll just go with that until I have a better reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

this.modal is not a single element, instead it is a DOM object which is why you can not bind anything on it. Try binding $('.modal-screen', this.modal) instead.

Comment: Binding to `this.modal.find('.modal-screen')` should be the same as what you're saying, correct? I can't seem to find anything in `this.modal` except the `iframe`. Logging `this.modal.find('*')` gives me the iframe element. I can't seem to bind an event to it and I can't seem to grab any of the elements in it.